# angular web project failed to load page icon

Tags: html, angular

I just started this angular web project in Visual Studio 2017 Pro. It compiles, but when I load the `index.html` in Google Chrome, it keeps giving 404 error for an icon, the line of code in question is below:

`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">`

I've checked that '`favicon.ico`' file is in the same directory as the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure about how it should work with what you have offered above. What you could do is move the favicon to `/assets`, which is where images / icons / static data is normally stored in an Angular project and then point the reference to that looking like so.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/favicon.ico">
```

A direct path to it should help.